# How to upload mp4 files to MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud, mp4

I have created a project using next.js & node.js where a user can upload videos on it like instagram reels. I used multer package to upload the mp4 files to my public folder which is working fine. But I want to host my project on heroku and there I am not able to upload the file directly in public folder. How can I upload mp4 files directly on mongoDB Atlas instead of my public folder?